# How to read an input file from within a jar-File?

Tags: java

This code throws an error `javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file`:

```
 img = ImageIO.read(new File("Assets/Cards.png"));
```

Inside of eclipse this code works fine. The file is also exported with the jar.

How can I read an input file properly - in eclipse and in the exported application?

Comment: Do not EVER use `File` when the content you intend to access will eventually end up in a jar; use `MyClass.class.getResource()` instead. This is one of the three more classical Java mistakes in my book, along with believing that `String`s have an encoding (they do not), using `URLEncoder` for encoding query strings (it cannot), and this scenario as #3.

Comment: @fge You hit it on the head. I made this mistake the first time I had to do this in Java. Sean Powell: The getResource() method takes a little bit of effort to call properly. Look through the documentation, as it's really easy to mess up and/or misunderstand the file structure it searches through.

Comment: @fge thanks for the answer it worked. will avoid using File from now on thanks.

Comment: @Aaron3468 what doesn't help is that when a resource does not exist, such methods return null... See also [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10mD-_M_fXOU3LOP5hmqVTlcJhgn5FUCwTLIdor2Z4qM/edit#slide=id.g5b5131c37_0_30)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading input files from either a filesystem location or from within a jar (or war) is tricky.

You could use [`YourClass.class.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), or [`YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to access those files (there is also an [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) method, that accepts InputStreams)